DAX For duplicated values in first column, check if there are duplicated values in second column
I wrote a DAX formula which identifies duplicates in column "Number". The new created column has value "YES" or "NO".
Now to the problem I cannot figure out:  I need to check for rows with duplicated value in column "Number", do they have differnt value in "Biz Type". "Biz Type" could have only two vaules "SP" and "PC".
The output is in the example below, highlighted in yellow. If there is a duplicate in number and differnce in column "Biz type" result is "No"
Could you help me with the DAX formula. Thank you in advance!


Can you include the tried dax measure in the question?

pls try this to create a column
Column=
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Biz Type] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Number] )
    )
VAR _count2 =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Number] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( _count2 = 1, "N/A", IF ( _count = 1, "YES", "NO" ) )



Your solution solved my problem. Thank you! One more question If I may. Lets say I have duplicated value in [Number] column. If one of the values in [Bizytpe] is null , formula treats it as "NO". This is correct behavior but,  can you make formula to ignore this scenario, put "N/A" instead. Thank you!

I added one more variable to solve my issue but new IF condition is not  working as expected.
VAR _count3= if(isblank(ZilliantTable[Business Type]),0,1)
RETURN
IF ( _count2 = 1, "N/A", IF ( _count = 1, "YES", if(_count3= 0, "N/A", "NO") ) )
